# Unable to find a page link's url.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Our company is trying to link a page from a website that's using this code for the link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="startBusinessIntent('guest','Retail','Craft/Hobby Vendor','Guest','BWPublic','Craft/Hobby Vendor');return false;">Craft/Hobby Vendor</a>
```

The website is the [NY License Center](https://bw.licensecenter.ny.gov/BW/businessTypeAction.els)

What we're trying to do is...

If you click that link and type in "vendor" in the Search box, it should come up with a page that looks like this:

> **Business Type Your search for vendor resulted in 2 business types.**
>
> Select a business type to obtain information on New York's
>   requirements for you to conduct this business activity.  You will be
>   guided through a series of questions related to your chosen activity. 
>   You must answer all questions to receive a summary of the licenses and
>   information you need to start your business.
>
> Craft/Hobby Vendor  Food/Beverage Vendor

We're trying to link either that entire page or to the least, the "Craft/Hobby Vendor" link. Because that link uses an "onclick" script, I'm not entirely sure as to how to fetch the URL to link that particular page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would have added a comment, but I'm not able to yet.

You posted the url that points to the javascript code, but you would have needed to include a javascript code file or code embedded in your html.  So if you could include a link to the code file or post the relevant code ...

Even still, it may not be possible.  You may want to contact them to see if they have a better way of doing it instead of reverse engineering.

Comment: I'm not quite savvy with coding of any sort, could you perhaps explain what I should do step-by-step to achieve this?

I do have access to our website's FTP.